# Trouble with decorator pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to learn decorator pattern and I have problem with it.

Firstly I have an interface

```
public interface MyCar {
    public String getMessage(int speed);
    public int getPrice();
}
```

I implemented this class like this;

```
public class Car implements MyCar{
    protected int price;
    protected boolean feature1;
    protected boolean feature2;

    public Car(){
        this.price = 0;
        this.feature1 = false;
        this.feature2 = false;
    }
    publicCar(int price){
        this.price = price;
        this.feature1 = false;
        this.feature2 = false;
    }

    int getPrice(){
        return price + (feature1 ? 1000 : 0) + (feature2 ? 2000 : 0);
    }
}
```

After that I derived two cars from this class like

```
public class Car1 extends Car{
    private static int price = 20000;

    public Car1() {
        super(price);
    }
}
```

Car2 class is exactly the same except from price which is 30000.

After this point I created a car decorator class which is;

```
public abstract class CarDecorator extends Car {
    protected Car decoratedCar;

    public CarDecorator(){
        decoratedCar = new Car();
    }

    public CarDecorator(Car decoratedCar) {
        this.decoratedCar = decoratedCar;
    }

    public int getPrice(){
        return this.decoratedCar.getPrice();
    }
}
```

Finally I have created 2 decorater class derived from CarDecorator:

```
public class F1Decorator extends CarDecorator{

    public F1Decorator(Car car) {
        super(car);
        decoratedCar.feature1 = true;
    }
}

public class F2Decorator extends CarDecorator{

    public F2Decorator(Car car) {
        super(car);
        decoratedCar.feature2 = true;
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Car car1 = new Car1();
        System.out.println("Price: " + car1.getPrice());

        car1 = new F1Decorator(car1);
        System.out.println("Price: " + car1.getPrice());

        car1 = new F2Decorator(car1);
        System.out.println("Price: " + car1.getPrice());
    }
}
```

And the output is

```
Price: 20000
Price: 21000
Price: 21000
```

Why feature2 does not have any effect on car1. What is wrong with my design. If you can help, I guess I will understand decorator pattern very well.

Comment: I don't see `feature2` being used in the `getPrice` method.  Perhaps it should be used there.

Comment: sorry for typo. I have editted it. Just copy paste mistake. Problem still occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you decorate `car1` with the `F1Decorator`, you return the `F1Decoorator`, which is a `Car`.  The constructor sets `feature1` on the original `car1`.  This new decorated car is assigned back to `car1`.

However, when you decorate `car1` again with `F2Decorator`, you are decorating the `F1Decorator`, not the original `Car`.  You are setting `F1Decorator`'s `feature2`, not the original `Car`'s `feature2`.  Because of this, `feature2` on the original `Car` is still `false`, and the price remains `21000`.

Introduce and call methods on `Car` and the decorator classes that will pass through the setting of features to the `Car`.

In `Car`:

```
public void setFeature1(boolean feat1)
{
   this.feature1 = feat1;
}

public void setFeature2(boolean feat2)
{
   this.feature2 = feat2;
}
```

In `CarDecorator`:

```
public void setFeature1(boolean feat1)
{
   this.decoratedCar.setFeature1(feat1);
}

public void setFeature2(boolean feat2)
{
   this.decoratedCar.setFeature2(feat2);
}
```

In `F1Decorator`:

```
public F1Decorator(Car car) {
    super(car);
    // Replace the assignment with this line.
    decoratedCar.setFeature1(true);
}
```

And in `F2Decorator`:

```
public F2Decorator(Car car) {
    super(car);
    decoratedCar.setFeature2(true);
}
```

With these changes, the output is now:

```
Price: 20000
Price: 21000
Price: 23000
```